# IOS steals focus from first input element for some reason

Tags: ios, safari, material-ui

working on a React/Material-UI based series of forms.  The autofocus HTML property works as expected, but for some strange reason the page, upon load, is stealing focus away from the first text field, and applying it somewhere in the middle.

This is especially annoying since I have validation onBlur, which will throw up a little error message saying to the user that the first field needs to be filled out.  How do I keep iOS Safari from stealing that focus?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this using `TextField` with multiline set to true (rendering a `<textarea>`). I'm not sure why, but I was able to narrow it down to a `minHeight` that I had set on the `textareaStyle` prop for `TextField`. My problem showed up on both iOS and Safari so I'm guessing it's got to do something with webkit. Removing the `minHeight` rule solved my issue of the focus being stolen.